# BlurTransformation doesn't work when when the radius is over 25

Tags: android, android-glide

I am trying to blur image in using Glide, hence I have created a custom BlurTransformation like following

```
public class BlurTransformation extends BitmapTransformation {

    private RenderScript rs;

    public BlurTransformation(Context context) {
        super();

        rs = RenderScript.create(context);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @Override
    protected Bitmap transform(BitmapPool pool, Bitmap toTransform, int outWidth, int outHeight) {

        Bitmap blurredBitmap = toTransform.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        // Load up an instance of the specific script that we want to use.
        ScriptIntrinsicBlur script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));

        // Allocate memory for Renderscript to work with
        Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, blurredBitmap, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_FULL, Allocation.USAGE_SHARED);
        Allocation output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.getType());


        script.setInput(input);

        // Set the blur radius
        script.setRadius(25);

        // Start the ScriptIntrinisicBlur
        script.forEach(output);

        // Copy the output to the blurred bitmap
        output.copyTo(blurredBitmap);

        return blurredBitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDiskCacheKey(MessageDigest messageDigest) {
        messageDigest.update("blur transformation".getBytes());
    }
}
```

It does the job , but the only problem is it doesn't work when I put `script.setRadius(25)` over `25`.

I know there is a library for this `https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations` , but I do not want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documents, max blur radius is 25. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicBlur.html#setRadius(float)